# How can I send a prop to a Component without using the component tag?

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, jsx

I'd like to send a paramater as a prop to another component, but whenever I use the component tag it will obviously execute the render method inside this component which I don't want to render. Any tips?

```
render() {

    return(
        <FlatList 
        data={this.state.dbData} 
        renderItem={({item}) => {
            return(
                <TouchableHighlight title="Client" onPress={ () => {
                    <Client selectedItem={item} />
                    this.props.navigation.navigate('ClientScreen');
                } }>

                    <CardSection><Text>{item.id}</Text></CardSection>
                </TouchableHighlight>

                    );
                }
            } 
        keyExtractor={item => item.id.toString()} />
    );
}
```

So the only way to send a prop to Client is using the Component tag, but that makes it render to the screen.

Comment: Are you trying to update a prop without forcing a re-render? because if that's the case, react native gives you this https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate

Comment: I'm trying to send a prop to a Container, but I don't to render it

Comment: want to render it*

Comment: Why would you want to do that? There might be other solutions to your problem if we know what the problem is.

Comment: It's a FlatList that renders a database and when I click a specific item, it should redirect the user to another screen, and this screen must receive an item prop